# How to get the actual values from a SQL join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `[dbo].Notifications` and `[dbo].ClientsNotifications` where :

`[dbo].Notifications`:

```
ID : Notification
1  : 'Notification1'
2  : 'Notification2'
3  : 'Notification3'
and so on...
```

and

`[dbo].ClientsNotifications`:

```
Id : ClientId : NotificationId
1  :    1     :      1
2  :    2     :      2
3  :    1     :      3
4  :    5     :      2
and so on..
```

What I want is by given `ClientId` to fetch all the string values from `[dbo].Notifications`.SELECT *

I tried something like this :

```
FROM [dbo].Notifications c, [dbo].ClientsNotifications a
WHERE a.ClientId IN (
        SELECT c.Notification
        FROM  [dbo].ClientsNotifications a2, [dbo].Notifications c2
        WHERE a2.ClientId = 1
    )
```

but it gives me this error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Notification1' to data type int.

I'm not very experienced in SQL so I'm not certain that this is even the right way (query) to fetch this data. At the end I want to get all string value notifications for user so I can show them in the view.

Comment: that error suggests you're trying to select an INT field which was initially assigned the NVARCHAR field type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
select n.Notification
from   Notifications n
where  n.Id in
       ( select cn.NotificationId
         from   ClientNotifications cn
         where  cn.ClientId = 1
       )
```

It selects all notifications where there is a matching record in `ClientNotifications`. There is no need for a `join` since you only wish the `Notification` field. If you *do* need values from that other table, use this:

```
select n.Notification
,      cn.ClientId /* some fields from ClientNotifications */
from   Notifications n
join   ClientNotifications cn
on     n.Id = cn.NotificationId
where  cn.ClientId = 1
```

Comment: I'm sure that all the answers with `Join` works but actually this was my first idea and I wanted to specifically use this approach. Your answer is working excellent so I'll accept it. Thanks to you and to everybody else.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to grab the ClientID from a list of Notification messages. Try:

```
SELECT Notification
FROM  Notifications
JOIN ClientsNotifications
ON Notifications.ClientId = ClientsNotifications.ClientId
WHERE ClientId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting notifincation strings in the subquery and try to fetch the records where the client id is the same as the notification string. That doesn't only compare data of different type (hence the error), it also compares values that has nothing to do with each other.

You should use a join in the query rather than a subquery:

```
select
  c.Notification
from
  [dbo].ClientsNotifications a
  inner join [dbo].Notifications c on c.ID = a.NotificationId
where
  a.ClientId = 1
```

Comment: I really appreciate answers where the actual mistake is explained. Since my question was about using subquery I'll accept `Patrick's` answer, but yours is very useful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.Notification -- The text of the notification record
FROM [dbo].Notifications n 
INNER JOIN [dbo].ClientsNotifications cn -- join Notifications table to ClientNotifications table
ON n.Id = cn.NotificationId -- when Notification.Id matches ClientNotification.NotificationId
WHERE cn.ClientId = 1 -- where ClientId = 1
```

Using an inner join should be more efficient than using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery will return varchar (Notification1, Notification2 or Notification3) :

```
SELECT c.Notification
    FROM  [dbo].ClientsNotifications a2, [dbo].Notifications c2
    WHERE a2.ClientId = 1
```

I assume you just change your subquery to make it works

```
    SELECT c.ID
    FROM  [dbo].ClientsNotifications a2, [dbo].Notifications c2
    WHERE a2.ClientId = 1
```